# STM32 ADC Averaging Values

Tags: stm32, noise, adc, stm32cubeide

I would like to get peak value from STM32 adc samples. I have written the below code and I've managed to get peak value however most of the time this value includes the biggest noise. In order to eliminate noise effects, I have decided to apply averaging method. I would like to get 5 measurements' averages. Then I'd like to compare these averages and use the biggest one(biggest average). Can anybody suggest a code?

Regards,

Umut

```
void HAL_ADC_ConvCpltCallback(ADC_HandleTypeDef* hadc)
    {
    ADC_raw = HAL_ADC_GetValue(hadc);
    Vdd = 3.3 * (ADC_raw)/4095;
    if (Vdd > Vmax)
      {
        Vmax = Vdd;
        }
```

Answer (score 2):

At first, I would remove as much code as possible from the Callback function because it is still inside the interrupt context which should be as short as possible. This is mentioned in a lot of answears here so I will not go into details on how to handle this.

For averaging the measurement, there are multiple ways you can go.

### Automatic avarage

Use the ADCs oversampling function. The controller will sample the signal multiple times (configure using OVFS register) and calculate an average value before triggering the interrupt.

### Manual average

Using the `HAL_ADC_ConvCpltCallback` function Store the numer of desired value into an array and calculate the average in the main loop.

### Manual average using DMA

Let the DMA store the number of samples you want to use in an array using the function `HAL_ADC_Start_DMA`. When all samples have been collected you will be notified. This will reduce the processor load because you don't have to shift the data into the array yourself.

---

You can also combine the oversampling (most of the time a good idea) and one of the other methods depending on your Use-Case.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. I'll look for how to reduce the callback function's codes.  In terms of averaging methods my microcontroller's adc does not have an automatic average mode.(STM32F101C8T6) I can use manual average mode and take five samples averages however I would like to compare averages. What would be the proper way to do it?